# How can I get Finder to show me the real names of my files?

Tags: macos, finder

On a Mac OS X 2.6.5 in the finder I renamed a file from `test2.xls` to `test2.xlsTEMP`:

[image]

However, at the UNIX command line, I see that the **REAL** name of the file is `test2.xlsTEMP.xls`:

[image]

**How can I get Finder to show me the real names of my files?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check *Finder (menu) » Preferences » Advanced » Show all filename extensions*.

[image]

---

Alternatively, select the file and press `Cmd-I`, or open the context menu and select *Get Info*. In this window, you see (and can edit) the full filename, as well as specify whether to display the individual file's extension:

[image]

---

Also worth mentioning is that your renaming issue only appears for extensions that aren't recognized by Finder:

[image]

<sup>(I know, not useful. Sue me!)</sup>

Just don't abuse the file extension for tagging files like this.